# Selenium not finding Google AutoService

Tags: java, selenium

I'm just getting started with Selenium, and Selenium can't find Google AutoService (which I assume is included in the Selenium download).

I'm definitely including all Selenium JARs on the classpath.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
        "/path/to/chromedriver");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("https://google.com");
     }
}
```

What I have so far should simply navigate to Google (I basically copy-pasted it from some online tutorials). When I compile, I get

```
...Selenium\client-combined-3.141.59- 
sources.jar(/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriverService.java):100: 
error: cannot find symbol
  @AutoService(DriverService.Builder.class)
   ^
  symbol:   class AutoService
  location: class ChromeDriverService
```

Comment: Did you just add Selenium to your PATH? Sometimes you have to close and reopen your IDE for it to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem two months ago.
A genius developped a library to provide updated WebDrivers: [WebDriverManager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager)
Code example [here](https://github.com/IQbrod/computer-database/commit/fb0eed2821e55a6e730ec704e8d7a8f094968ca1)